# Oracle - generate unique random varchar values for each row of a table

Tags: oracle, random, unique-constraint, varchar2

I have to update a 'varchar2' column in a table with random values, but the catch is that the column is defined with 'unique' constraint, due to which I am getting the error saying that "Unique constraint violated".

Can somebody help please.

Thanks

Comment: why you want to update random value any specific reason

Comment: because the existing values are not to be shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `DBMS_RANDOM` package to create the random values and insert the same in table like below

```
INSERT INTO table_name(unique_col) values (DBMS_RANDOM.string('a',n);
```

here *n* can be max value of table. For more information refer here http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random.php

The value generated will be `unique` depends on the length of the value

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any constraints over what the values might be, so why not just set it to a set of known unique values, e.g. integers:

```
UPDATE table_name SET unique_col = TO_CHAR(ROWNUM);
```

Comment: Or just use the ROWID if ROWNUM doesn't "look" random enough.